# LINQ-Query to split a List (ordered by DateTime asc) of Objects into sublists by daterange

Tags: c#, linq, list, date

So, I have a `Basket` here containing `BasketItems`. Each of this Items has a `MenuDate`. Now I want to create `Orders` out of these Items, where the condition is: Every `Order` should have the Items of one week (starts on monday here) in it.

Now I know, I can  create multiple foreach-constructs, maybe even a while(true) where I check all the dates and everytime a monday is hit, but this all seems a bit hacky to me. Optimal it would be, to have a LINQ-Query somehow like this Code I'Ve written, but this does not give the expected values back:

```
var basketItems = currBasket.Items.OrderBy(y => y.MenuDate).ToList();
            if (basketItems.Count() > 0)
            {
                List<List<BasketDay>> listOfItemsPerWeek = basketItems
                .GroupBy(p => p.MenuDate >= basketItems.First().MenuDate.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday) 
                            && p.MenuDate < basketItems.First().MenuDate.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(7))
                .Select(g => g.ToList())
                .ToList();
            }
```

where startofweek is an extensionmethod I use giving me the previous monday of a given datetime (or monday if its monday, for sure).

which gives me a number of `List<BasketDay>` containing all menus out of currBasket.Items whose MenuDates are lying inbetween monday and sunday (23:59:59).

I've tried everything so far and now I am out of ideas and hope you could help me out here.

Beste regards

**edit:**

To make it clear, assume we're in the food branche here: `BasketDay` contains a menu for a day.

Here's an example use case (removed year for its not that important here): 
Customer adds menus to a basket for the following dates in january:

monday 01.01., 
wednesday 03.01. 
friday 05.01.
sunday 07.01.
monday 08.01.
tuesday 09.01.

so his basket contains 6 items.

Now what I need is: To Separate this one List of `BasketDay` instances into weekly `List<BasketDay>`.

The LINQ-Query above should do this for me. After that, I could create separate order-objects like this:

```
foreach(weekOrder in listOfItemsPerWeek){...}
```

where `listOfItemsPerWeek` contains 2 `List<BasketDay>`, one with 4 items (01.01. - 07..01.) and the second with 2 items (08.01. and 09.01.)

hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: Is `BasketDay` the `Order` you are talking about? It's not that clear what you want. What is the desired key of the group? Sometimes LINQ doesn't help to make your code  more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to declare a temporary variable that can be used to `group by`, e.g. calendar week might be a good choice here.

```
var calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;

var items = (from item in basketItems
             let calendarWeek = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(item.MenuDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)
             group item by calendarWeek into baskets
             select baskets);
```

**Edit:** `CalendarWeekRule` selects how the first week of the year is determined. This differs from culture to culture and I chose the [ISO definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) which is used here in Germany. Since you are only interested in grouping from monday to sunday the absolut value might be irrelevant to you and so you can chose whatever rule you like. If you prefer Lambda the code looks like this:

```
var calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;

var items = basketItems.GroupBy(i => calendar.GetWeekOfYear(i.MenuDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday));
```

Comment: thank you very much for this solution. Two questions, though: 1) is this possible as a lambda, as I did in the question? I've searched for using `let`but didn'T find something. 
2) Could you please explain what `CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek` does in this context? It's somewhat unclear for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate week of the year(week number) for each item then you can simply group on week of the year. Here is how i will do it, i have also assumed that we have multiple year date range, so the grouping will be on year and week number, i have set the starting of the week to Monday you can change it if you like

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ItemDate { get; set; }
}
public class ItemWithWeekInfo
{
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int WeekOfTheYear { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int WeekOfTheYear { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
var groups =  items.Select(p => new ItemWithWeekInfo
        {
            Year = p.ItemDate.Year,
            WeekOfTheYear = cal.GetWeekOfYear(p.ItemDate, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, DayOfWeek.Monday),
            Item = p
        }).GroupBy(p => new { p.Year , p.WeekOfTheYear}).Select(p=>new Order
        {
            Year = p.Key.Year,
            WeekOfTheYear = p.Key.WeekOfTheYear,
            Items = p.Select(x=> x.Item).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

This will work if you have the list already, but if you are making the database call you will not be able to do this, then you will need to use some database supported function to calculate the year and week number.